# Gnome 3 - custom keyboard shortcut to run command as root?

Tags: fedora, sudo, gnome3, keyboard-backlight

My keyboard backlight function keys don't seem to work, so I've written a script to change the keyboard brightness, which must be run as root.  It is invoked like so...

```
sudo /usr/bin/local/backlight inc
sudo /usr/bin/local/backlight dec
```

This works fine from the terminal, but it doesn't work as the command of a custom keyboard shortcut I created via keyboard settings.

Just guessing here, but might the issue be that the command, when invoked via the keyboard shortcut, is not actually running under my user, but as someone else, which wouldn't be in the sudoers file?

Comment: Do you normally need to type a password when you run a command via `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

Gnome 3 uses an authorization mechanism called [polkit](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) so the right way to run that executable as root is via [pkexec](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html):

> pkexec allows an authorized user to execute PROGRAM as another user.
>   If username is not specified, then the program will be executed as the
>   administrative super user, root.

To authorize the user in the active session to run that command as root you'll have to define a new action (as per the above spec) via a `XML` file under `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` , let's call it `org.fedora.pkexec.kbback.policy`.

Content of `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.fedora.pkexec.kbback.policy`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>

  <icon_name>input-keyboard</icon_name>
  <action id="org.fedora.pkexec.kbback">
    <message>Authentication is required to Change Keyboard Backlight</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>no</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/local/bin/backlight</annotate>
  </action>

</policyconfig>
```

Next step is to assign the commands to your keyboard shortcuts via GNOME keyboard settings:

```
pkexec /usr/local/bin/backlight inc
pkexec /usr/local/bin/backlight dec
```

(note: I used `/usr/local/bin/backlight` as the path for my executable, you'll have to alter the action file and the two commands if your executable path is different)

Comment: Did this, but the shortcut still doesn't seem to function.  I can, however, run the command from the terminal, and it works.  

Good news though, I just installed a system update, and the back-light function keys began to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `gksudo` in this case. I quote from the `gksudo(1)` man page:

> gksu  is a frontend to su and gksudo is a frontend to sudo.  Their pri‐
>          mary purpose is to run graphical commands that need  root  without  the
>          need to run an X terminal emulator and using su directly

So it would seem that the issue here is that the commands launched by the keyboard shortcut do not have a (pseudo) terminal device hooked up to them, which causes `sudo` to fail and `gksudo` should be used instead.

Comment: Dang, looks like gksudo doesn't exist in Fedora (Fedora 20) anyways.  I'll look around for an alternative.

Comment: @Josiah There seems to be an [alternative](http://linux.die.net/man/1/beesu) called [Beesu](http://honeybeenet.altervista.org/beesu/) but I'm not sure if it's part of the "official" distribution. Use at your own risk and please don't deploy in a production multi-user environment until you're sure it's safe.

Comment: @Josiah Another alternative may be if your keyboard shortcut can be configured to "Run in a terminal". Have you tried that?

Comment: I remember that option in gnome2, but I don't see it here.