# Run specific command from .desktop with root

Tags: sudo, .desktop

I have a program that I wish all users of my linux install to be able to run with root privileges from a .desktop file.

Currently in my .desktop file I have:

```
Exec=gksu command
```

but this of cause displays the gksu prompt. 
I assume I need to add a entry to my sudoers file to allow any user to run this command with root so that the .desktop file can just have:

```
Exec=command
```

However I am now sure how to set this up for all users.

Comment: If it is an executable (not a script) it might be easier to SUID and have it owned by root.

Comment: I would have said it is a sh script

Comment: @ZacPowell - if your system is using policykit you could define a new polkit action, see my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158938/22142).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a non Red Hat distro then you can likely use `gksudo` to get a graphical prompt and then have the user's with the ability to run this single command via `sudo`.

For Fedora and other Red Hat distros you can use [PolicyKit](https://live.gnome.org/PolicyKit) (you may be able to use this on other distros as well, I'm not able to test this currently). PolicyKit includes the tool `pkexec`.

```
$ pkexec [--user username] PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]
```

#### References

- [no gksudo? so just su or sudo then?](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/7185/no-gksudo-so-just-su-or-sudo-then/)

Comment: Debian (and probably Debian-based distros, at least Ubuntu doesn't) doesn't have gksu/do by default either, while they have `pkexec` from the `policykit-1` package which in turn is dependency of `network-manager`. So, as long as you use network manager you can say the polkit is instaled.